# Who would have the Sixers handed ownership of GSS to?

Tags: ready-player-one

In *Ready Player One* all of the Sixers are contractually obligated to hand over their winnings to IOI once they found the Easter egg:

> To become a Sixer, you had to sign a contract stipulating, among other things, that if you found Halliday’s egg, the prize would become the sole property of your employer.

If Sorrento, or any of the other Sixers, had gotten to the egg first, who would their prize have actually gone to? Would IOI the company own GSS? Would it be IOI’s CEO? Is there anything from the book or its sequel, or perhaps a statement from the author, that would explain who at IOI lost out?

Answer (score 1):

Sorrento, for all his egotism, is a favoured employee and not IOI the corporation, so presumably he would have been obligated to turn over the prize as well.

That said, while he could be legally compelled to turn over the ownership shares, it's not clear that the superuser powers formerly held by Anorak and passed on to Parsival could easily be transferred to a corporation.  (For one thing they seem to be bound to a specific user/avatar.)

Comment: After a sleep I realise that I worded my question poorly. Who would have Sorrento (or any of the Sixers) been forced to give up the prize to? I know he wasn’t the top employee, so someone was higher, but do we know who would have assumed control of GSS? Either we know this, or we don’t.